# Join when table A has duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates, sum

My head is about to explode with everything I've read about SQL Server and Joins in the last 2 hours.

```
tbl_customers
-------------
IPaddress
CustomerID


tbl_purchases
-------------
OrderID (pkey)
CustomerID
OrderTotal
```

I want to get the total purchase amounts per IP address. There are more columns in the tbl_customers table, such that there are duplicate (IPaddress, CustomerID) rows. I have used the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IPaddress, SUM(OrderTotal) FROM tbl_customers a
INNER JOIN tbl_purchases b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
GROUP BY IPaddress;
```

But it retrieves the duplicate rows from tbl_customers and causes the sum function to count the same purchase multiple times. What am I doing wrong? Efficiency isn't really an issue as I'm dealing with under 10K records.

Comment: Perhaps IPaddress should be in tbl_purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tc.IPaddress,SUM(tp.OrderTotal)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IPaddress,CustomerID FROM tbl_customers) tc,
     tbl_purchases tp
WHERE tc.CustomerID = tp.CustomerID
GROUP BY tc.IPaddress;
```

OR

```
SELECT tc.IPaddress,SUM(tp.OrderTotal)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IPaddress,CustomerID FROM tbl_customers) tc
              INNER JOIN 
             tbl_purchases tp
             ON   tc.CustomerID = tp.CustomerID
 GROUP BY tc.IPaddress;
```

Comment: why are you using commas to join the tables instead of JOIN (INNER/LEFT) syntax?

Comment: @jlarkins using comma instead of JOIN is just a different way of the syntax. If I remember correct the table1, table2 and using WHERE statement was before INNER JOIN was introduced in SQL. So you can use comma sperated and move the join clause to the WHERE statement or you use INNER JOIN as you prefer.

Comment: In the event that a customer has multiple IPs, this report will sum to a higher purchase amount than actually exists in tbl_purchases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it sounds like your DB is not normalized.  If you have a table for customers, and multiple rows with the same CustomerId, does the table have a primary key or is this supposed to be the key to identify a customer?

Comment: tbl_customers isn't for holding customers as such, my example has been sanitized for public posting.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the total purchase amounts per IP address.

Using your current schema, if a customer makes purchases from more than one IP, then you cannot possibly get such an amount (unless you want to average the amount over all of that customer's IPs or something).  Perhaps `IPaddress` should be in `tbl_purchases`.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but as I'm compiling the data in these tables from multiple other sources, I don't have that privilege. At least, I haven't figured out how to yet.

Comment: Do you have customers with multiple IPs? If so, you can't meet the stated requirement, or you have to choose one IP to apply the sales to, or average them or something.

Comment: In the case of a customer with multiple IPs, I would want to count their order total for both IPs. So if Bob has a $500 order from 192.168.1.1 and a $300 order from 192.168.1.2, I'd want to see $800 associated with each IP.